# When creating a selling plan using GraphQL in shopify store , productIDs does not store

Tags: graphql, shopify

1. [Mutation for create selling plan]
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNjQJ.png)
2. [In variables : "resource" not working so, productIds not store in
   selling plan] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LXsA.png)
3. [Result of created selling plan product count is
   0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UgRu.png)

I expect to store multiple products in the selling plan

Answer (score 0):

Your GQL is incorrect in that when you assign to the **resources** attribute you are assigning an array of productIds not a singular product. Try changing your GQL to

```
 resources: {
      productVariantIds: ["gid://shopify/ProductVariant/39606641322169"],
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But
I was forgot to declare resource variable ( $resouces: SellingPlanGroupResourceInput! ) in Mutation